# Python how to filter a csv based on a column value and get the row count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to do data insepction and print count of rows that matches a certain value in one of the columns. So below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("census.csv")
```

The census.csv has a column "income" which has 3 values '<=50K', '=50K' and '>50K'
and i want to print number of rows that has income value '<=50K'

i was trying like below

```
count = data['income']='<=50K'
```

That does not work though.

Comment: `data.income.eq('<=50K').sum()`

Comment: This is simplest. if you post it as an answer then i can mark it correct.

Comment: feel free to accept wwnde's answer since it's basically the same now after the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum Boolean selection

```
(data['income'].eq('<50K')).sum()
```

Comment: This is not right as the value itself is '<50K' as string.

Comment: See my edits, just though yo had abbreviated value

Answer (score 1):

The key is to learn how to filter pandas rows.

#### Quick answer:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("census.csv")
df2 = data[data['income']=='<=50K']

print(df2)
print(len(df2))
```

#### Slightly longer answer:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("census.csv")
filter = data['income']=='<=50K'
print(filter) # notice the boolean list based on filter criteria

df2 = data[filter]  # next we use that boolean list to filter data
print(df2)
print(len(df2))
```